# JSON MYSQL-PHP not getting object

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to retrieve an object from MYSQL with PHP and JSON. The object is selected from the app and should then be editable.
But I get an "No value for..." error in logcat, like this:

```
W/System.err(21945): org.json.JSONException: No value for product
```

After reading some Q&A here on SO I figure that it's something wrong with these lines, can you guys see any problems with it?

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
url_product_details, "GET", params1);

Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

// JSON success tag
success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
if (success == 1) {
// Successfully received product details
JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON array

// Get first product object from JSON Array
final JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
```

Thanks!

Comment: with that line there is nothing wrong. Simply you are not getting a entry in your json with key product

Comment: The app is first displaying all objects and then I click on one of the objects and an "Edit screen" opens and should fill in the name and phone number. I know that the object is there in the database but JSON cant find it. But you see nothing wrong in the above?

Comment: post the json you are getting from the server

Comment: If I'm not wrong this is the json:
`D/Single Product Details(21945): {"success":1,"test1":[{"PID":"2"}]}`

Comment: you are not wrong, but as you can see your json does not contains the product key